# Is there any framework that supports scanning ITF-14 barcodes reader on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, barcode-scanner

In my project I have to scan an ITF-14 barcode to obtain its data. I have tried both the ZBar framework and Zebra Crossing sample but neither can handle ITF-14 barcodes.

Is there another framework or piece of sample code out there that can handle this type of barcode?

Comment: Déjà vu? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597909/is-there-a-framework-that-supports-scanning-ean-14-barcodes-on-ios

Comment: I have already seen this link  http://shopsavvy.mobi/2010/07/30/scanner-kit-sdk-4-0-available-now/   is this working for scanning the ITF-14 Barcode reader?

Comment: Above link doesn't seem to work . Is there any other alternative to read barcodes from ITF - 14 format ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Zbar 0.4+ (2008) does support Interleave 2 of 5 (ITF-14 is a special case of it), but often needs to be enabled.
The reason I2of5 is often disabled is that it has a lot of false positives which makes it a bad choice of format when given the choice. ITF14 solves that problem by forcing 14 digits, but that's besides the point.

```
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 1];
```

Should allow you to scan ITF14.

Personally I've had a hard time reading I25. It seems to depend a lot on module-width (how fat the bars are), lighting, and medium / background color.

Feel free to add more descriptions of your problem (or open a new thread? @Dhruv)